# jQuery Autocomplete Uncaught TypeError

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

the script below works fine when the file is in the root folder but when I move it to a folder 3 levels in, it stops working. with an error on this line `$(this).autocomplete("/js/zip/" + $(this).data("code") + ".php", {` of course i changed out the url, to reflect the location of ../../js/zip, domain.com/js/zip/

**console error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete'**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/zip/jquery.autocomplete.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/zip/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#ctry").change(function() {
  $(".state").hide();
  var stateSelect = $("#state_" + $(this).val());
  stateSelect.show();      
});
$("input[data-code]").each(function() {
  $(this).autocomplete("/js/zip/" + $(this).data("code") + ".php", {
  matchContains: true, matchFirst: true, mustMatch: false,
  selectFirst: false, cacheLength: 10, minChars: 1, autofill: false,
  scrollHeight: 150, width: 180, max: 20, scroll: true
  });
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: check your developer tools network tab to see whether autocomplete js is loaded correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message is typical when the plugin did not load.  Check the console or network tabs (depending on which browser and tools you're using) and see if jquery.autocomplete.js failed to load.  You can also, prior to the line where the error occurs, write `console.log($);` and then you can inspect the jQuery object in the console and confirm that it is missing the autocomplete() method.

Comment: thanks. it appears I had jquery 1.7.0 and 1.7.1 loading on the same page. caused conflicts with each other. removed the old version and everything is working

Comment: Good.  Yeah, reloading jQuery after the plugin loads is another way to cause it, and it's a bad idea to try and load two versions in the same page.